# Opening multiple ASCII files (saved as consolidated binary) using Fortran in R

Tags: r, binary, ascii

I am working with some output from a program compiled in FORTRAN. The output the program produces are multiple ASCII (e.g. for each month of the years over which simulation was performed) files produced as a single binary file. I am trying to open this in R using readBin, but am struggling to understand how to approach this problem given my poor familiarity with binary encoding of information.
Included below is part of one of 12 ASCII files that are encoded as a binary file. Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated.

```
ncols                   26

 nrows                   24

 xllcorner        30.0000000    
 yllcorner       -6.00000000    
 cellsize        0.500000000    
 NODATA_value  -9999

4.44894731E-02     8.23551118E-02     7.33195692E-02    0.121438913      0.150726944        0.131888524         7.33321458E-02    0.102442160        0.181108430        0.289648712        0.269542843        0.160156175        0.218589276        0.149929196        0.199702621        0.308591902        0.170369297         2.12968588E-02     2.40366161E-02    0.149830237        0.178994611        0.247626245        0.288051009        0.208817780        0.277588427
```

Comment: If you need help with reading the binary file, are we supposed to be able to generate a binary file from this sample data?

Comment: My intention was only to show what each of the 12 files that are consolidated as one binary file look like.

Comment: I guess I don't understand, nothing about that looks binary, just a format that is non-trivial to parse. "Binary file" aside, you need help parsing a file that has that text? Sorry if I'm being dim.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. The program I am using prodcues an output that that is a binary file (e.g. cover.gof). That file is composed of ASCII files (12 total, 1 for each month of the year). I posted as an example of what any on of those ASCII files looks like. Perhaps, I have misunderstood the file structure myself. I am not sure if there is a way to attach the output file here?

Comment: Not easily while maintaining a self-contained reproducible question, unfortunately, since we can't help you `readBin` a file if we don't know what it looks like. While I'm generally not a fan, many have posted links to google drive, pastebin, and other data-sharing sites with the data.